# How can I tell what might be keeping my laptop from accessing Internet?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, google-chrome, android

For months now I've been blaming Comcast for bad wireless connections. That is until I got my first Smartphone.

One minute I'm buzzing all around the web and then the next minute pages won't load. Downtimes vary from short 30 second spats to sometimes more than an hour. While at the same time my phone leapfrogs from one site to the next as happy as can be.

This leads me to think that maybe something is running in the background that keeps me from having a continuous session.

Problem is I don't know how or what to check to find the culprit.

I have a Toshiba Satellite P55 running Win 8.1

Everything is always maintained as far as updates for the OS and all the general apps such as Java, Flash, etc.

Antivirus is up to date and malware scans come back clean.

I only use Google Chrome and recently I installed the beta version to see if that would help the problem. There was no difference.

At this point I'm not even sure what other information is needed to help find the answer here.

Phone works great all the time, laptop doesn't.

Ron W
Naples FL

Answer (score 1):

*going to put as answer due to character limit on Comments*

Hi Ron,

Well its good you have narrowed it down to your laptop that's the first part of troubleshooting done.

Now we have to dive a little deeper in to troubleshooting on your laptop to find out what could be cause;

I'm guessing your laptop is using wireless as well as your phone so that kind of rules out the wireless being the issue.

One of the first steps would be to see if your laptop can access the wireless routers web interface during this 'outage' time. Are you aware of how to get to this routers web page?

The next test would be to see if a network cable between your router and your laptop with wireless turned off stops these incidents happening.

After these two are tested we can go in to further troubleshooting but that is where I would start.

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: Hi Charles, I know how to access the wireless router and no, I cannot access it during the outage time. I haven't tried the network cable but I do know how to do that. I will try that next time I get the chance. Should have an answer for you hopefully by the end of the day. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: No problem Ron glad to help, definitely using a network cable would be the next thing to try. When you use the cable make sure your wireless is disabled on the laptop else it is likely to take priority over the network cable (even if its not working). I'll await your results and we can go from there!

Comment: Wow! That was fast! lol. I understand. TY